# Setting TCP Retransmission Timeout in C

Tags: c, networking, tcp

I have an small server/client test program I am running over a radio link using TCP/IP and I noticed with wireshark that I am getting a lot of retransmits due to high latency.  How do I increase the window my program waits for an ACK before attempting retransmission?

Update on OS:
The server is running Linux, the Client is on Windows

Comment: What is the operating system? The mechanism likely varies between OS-es.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Linux, you can try playing with the `TCP_WINDOW_CLAMP` and the other options from http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.30/include/linux/tcp.h#L85 . They can be set by using `setsockopt` (man 3 setsockopt), I think.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely this question needs some clarification.
IMO, best solution should be to switch to asynchronous sockets. This way timeout handling is all yours.

Answer (score 0):

[Windows](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/170359) and [Linux](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl7_tcp.htm) both ask you to configure parameter values. You could do that either on the server side or on the client side .. So which ever method suits you try it.